# Target Audience Count in LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

LinkedIn API v1 had an api endpoint to count the number of selected target audience. The later apis has this endpoint only for [Ads-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/audience-counts)

Now, I am trying to share posts using targeting criteria ([Share API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#share-distribution-targets)). I want to restrict posting if size of audience is less than 300. (As LinkedIn has a limit (audience size must be at least 300), I have to do a check first.) how do I count the size of target? (Note that, I have the count of individual categories with this [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics): but these audiences might have intersection, so the sum of these counts aren't accurate.)

How does others use targeting api without this? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Audience Counts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/audience-counts) API, where you can pass the [targetingCriteria](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/targeting-criteria?context=linkedin/marketing/context) as a list, as example:

```
curl \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer <the_token>" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" \
   "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/audienceCountsV2?q=targetingCriteriaV2&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3AinterfaceLocales:List(urn%3Ali%3Alocale%3Aen_US))),(or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Alocations:List(urn%3Ali%3Aregion%3A5636))))))"
```

Will return something like:

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "total": 1100000,
      "active": 0
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "count": 10,
    "start": 0,
    "links": []
  }
}
```

Take care of the correct encoding as described in the doc also.

**UPDATE**

In order to calculate organic post on a companyPage, you should add the followedCompanies criteria, as [described in the doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#target-organic-shares):

> The audience you target for your share must be greater than 300
>   members. Use the audienceCountsV2 API to calculate the approximate
>   size of your audience. Make sure to pass in your company URN in the
>   **followedCompanies** field of the targetingFacet parameter so your audience count will be filtered down to only members who follow your
>   company.

So referring to the previous example, for targeting a companyPage of ID = 123:

```
curl \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer token" \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" \
   "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/audienceCountsV2?q=targetingCriteriaV2&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3AfollowedCompanies:List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A123))),(or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3AinterfaceLocales:List(urn%3Ali%3Alocale%3Aen_US))),(or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Alocations:List(urn%3Ali%3Aregion%3A5636))))))"
```

Hope this help

Comment: this is for ads-api. I am trying to share posts from organization page.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake