# API to get the list of published post to create Ad and audience attribute list

Tags: api, linkedin-api, ads

I was unable to get the LinkedIn ads documentation for

1. Is there any LinkedIn marketing (Ads) API to get the list of published post to create ad from the existing content
2. Ads API get the audience attributes list like

   - Members with a Bachelor’s Degree
   - Expertise in Computer Science

and when it get selected it will get the list of target audience like **Computer Software Engineering, Computer Science, Computer Engineering, COMPUTER AND INFORMATION SCIENCES AND SUPPORT SERVICES,etc.**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the Links to the related doc:

**1. Retrieve User Content**

You can retrieve the user created post, with the UGC Post API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#retrieve-ugc-posts

As alternative you can fallback to the previous Share API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#find-shares-by-owner

Some SO Answers:

- [How to get posts of an organization from LinkedIn where Im the admin of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291683/how-to-get-posts-of-an-organization-from-linkedin-where-im-the-admin-of-the-page/56292978#56292978)
- [LinkedIn API: Server error while listing UGC posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505276/linkedin-api-server-error-while-listing-ugc-posts/56516774#56516774)

**2. Handling Ads Targeting**

The targeting for Ads is described in this section of the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ads-targeting

Useful links are about the [Targeting Criteria Facet URNs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/targeting-criteria-facet-urns), check also the [targetingCriteria Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/targeting-criteria-examples) page. The [Audience Counts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/audience-counts) API and the Ad [Supply Forecasts API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ad-supply-forecasts) could be useful for your scope.

Also useful SO answers:

- [Target Audience Count in LinkedIn API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944928/target-audience-count-in-linkedin-api/59945316#59945316)
- [Parameter 'targetingCriteria' is invalid for audience count with LinkedIn marketing API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65255274/parameter-targetingcriteria-is-invalid-for-audience-count-with-linkedin-market/65262998#65262998)
- [Ad Targeting - Find Entities by URNs API ClassCastException error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222238/ad-targeting-find-entities-by-urns-api-classcastexception-error-message)

**MORE ON TARGETING**

The list of available targeting facets is returned by the [Ad Targeting Facets API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ads-targeting): A sort of static list that describe for each fields, how you can retrieve the values (is a list or if you can query it).

When you have the facet urn, you can retrieve the values with the [Find Entities by Facet API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ads-targeting#ad-targeting-entities) or [Find Entities by Typeahead API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ads-targeting#find-entities-by-typeahead)

See also [Discovering targeting entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/ads-targeting#discovering-targeting-entities) section in the doc

As example:

for the degrees (urn:li:adTargetingFacet:degrees) you will use the Find Entities by Typeahead API in order to retrieve the whole list of available degrees.

for skills (urn:li:adTargetingFacet:skills) you can query for a search string using the Find Entities by Facet API

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Matteo i got the targeting audience document could you tell me the facet urn to get the list of audience attributes ? 
In Linkedin native it was displayed beside Saved Audience option and immediate to objective selection

Comment: Hi @Satya I've added a "MORE ON TARGETING" section. I hope you can start playing with the API with that